# How to get reference of a background file-download Task in Swift?

Tags: swift, background, urlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am successfully able to download a file in the background.
Upon App closing and App-reopening, there is still data downloaded as expected.

However, in order to show the UI according to data-download-state, I need a reference to the actual background-task. I especially would like to know if there is still a background-task running - and if yes, I need the reference to this particular one.

How would I do that ??

From what I read, this reference should automatically be given by the downloadSession that was configured as a background-session in the first place (i.e. `self.downloadService.downloadsSession = self.downloadsSession`). But this does not do it somehow...

Furthermore, I kill my App by a) press the stop-button in the simulator or b) by double-pressing Home and swiping the App out of the multithread-view --> is this valid for keeping background-tasks alive for next App-start ?? (at least the `didWriteData` method keeps firing with both closings a) or b) - so I assume this is ok)

Here is my code (excerts from a bigger project - but you should get the idea)...

```
let downloadService = SomeDownloadService()

lazy var downloadsSession: URLSession = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "SomeID.BGSessionConfiguration")
    return URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.downloadService.downloadsSession = self.downloadsSession

    // ...file is created somewhere else...
    self.downloadService.startDownload(file)
    // *** Until here everything OK - file starts downloading in the background *******

    // *** HOW DO I GET A REFERENCE TO THE BACKGROUND TASK RUNNING ???????
    // ????

    // *** KEEPS PRINTING 0 *** WHY ?????????????????????????
    print(self.downloadService.activeDownloads.count
}

// Updates progress info
// *** WORKS WELL - upon second App-Start there is still data coming in *******
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url,
        let download = self.downloadService.activeDownloads[url]  else {
            return
    }

    download.progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)

    let totalSize = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: totalBytesExpectedToWrite, countStyle: .file)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you created the task, with `downloadTask(with:)`, you were returned a `URLSessionDownloadTask`. As long as your program is still running, you can use that task to access the download information. I believe your question is how to handle this when your program is terminated and relaunched.

Every task has a `taskIdentifier`. You can create a dictionary mapping identifiers to whatever is useful for your internal tracking (URL, constant, whatever). When you relaunch, you can call `URLSession.shared.getTasksWithCompletionHandler()` to retrieve all the in-progress tasks, and use the identifiers to map back to whatever you're using to track them.

If the only thing you care about is the URL, you can skip the whole identifier step, and just use the `originalRequest` to figure out which one you care about.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rob, for the detailed answer. I'll give it a try !

Comment: It works - except: If I navigate away from the VC that started the DownloadTask and re-enter it (either by `segue to Detail-VC` or by persistence of properties and `storyboard!.instantiateVC`): A re-entering of a VC does no longer update UI (such as progressBar or progressLabel ! (re-entering kicks in nicely [by method you described] in the delegate methods (such as `urlSession(...didWriteData bytesWritten...)` or `urlsSession(...didFinischDownloadingTo location...)` - but again: No UIProgressView- or UILabel will update the UI if altered inside one of the two mentioned delegate-methods !

Comment: Please also refer to this question I opened because this issue drives me nuts since 2 days !! [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059624/progress-bar-freeze-after-navigationcontroller-back-action)

Comment: @iKK View Controllers should not manage download tasks (or any network behaviors). They are only responsible for their view, while onscreen. Network operations happen independently of that. You need to move network operations to a lower-level object that is independent of what happens to be on screen.

Comment: I do have everything in a lower level object - no issue. But the two delegate-methods (`urlSession(...didWriteData bytesWritten...)` or `urlSession(...didFinischDownloadingTo location...)` happen to be in a VC (that delegates from `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`). And this VC is currently responsible for a progress update on the UI. So in that case, you are saying that there is no ProgressBar-kicking-in possibility once the VC re-enters (or the App restarts) ? Or how would I get the reference back to the progress already done - and moreover how would I present it in a View (if not through a VC) ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the UIViewController fetches a `NSProgress` from the task, it should be able to get updates. (Ah, from your updated comment I see the problem. Use the `.progress` property, not the delegate methods.)

Comment: Yes - it does. And I can print(download.progress) in the Debug-window - no issue. BUT any UIProgressView or UILabels updated (of course all inside `DispatchQueue.main.async{...}` do not work anymore (UI frozen !!! - no progressBar movement. You can try it. The UI does it well - but once you leave the VC and RE-ENTER it (by segue or instantiate-VC) - that's when the misery happens.

Comment: Ah - how so ?? .progress property ?? Inside the `(urlSession(...didWriteData bytesWritten...)` method, I get the download back as such:  `guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url, let download = self.downloadService.activeDownloads[url]  else { return }` and then  I do the following:  `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.progressBarOutlet.progress = Float(download.progress)}` What is wrong with that ??? AGAIN: IT ONLY DOES NOT DO THE JOB ONCE I RE-ENTER THE VC (it all works nicely when the VC is entered the first time) ! You have to try this Re-entering.

Comment: I mean, fetch the `task.progress`, and attach that directly to your `UIProgressView`. You don't need the delegate.

Comment: How do I do that from a VC (or View) - so far, I only have the task.progress inside one of the `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` delegate-methods (that give me nice timely callbacks useful to update the progressBar). Would I have to run some sort of timer ? Or what do you have in mind if you say "fetch task.progress" ? How do I "attach" that "directly to my UIProgressView" ??

Comment: Look at `UIProgressView.observedProgress`. You get the the `NSProgress` from the task after you fetched it with `getTasksWithCompletionHandler`.  See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/232/ to understand NSProgress.

Comment: Thank you, Rob ! I will have a look at it !! I appreciate your patience :)

Comment: It works now !!!!! : Oh Rob, you have been a great help ! :) I did not know about this `.progress` attachment-possibility of a download-task. I am learning fast :). Thank you very very much for you help here !

Comment: Rob - sorry to bother you again: But the progressBar-freeze is not over yet :/  ([please see sample project here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132845/ui-freezes-after-re-entering-detail-vc-during-urlsession-background-downloadtask)). Any help on this highly appreciated !!